# setting the session variable again after a button click in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am working on a jsp page.after logging in a session is being set and everything is working fine. But there is a feature in the website after clicking a button I am taking value of the button from jquery and need to set the session again.
How do I do that?

How to set the session variable again to the value stored in the `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are maintained on the server side. So, You can't store in in the Javascript.

What I suggest is on  your button click, take value and make Ajax request to server (Usually a Servlet) and store the updated value in the session.

As you are already using `jQuery`. you can do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myButton').click(function(){
           sendData();
    });
   });
function sendData(){
   var myVal = $('#myText').val();
    alert(myVal);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UtilServlet", // Map your servlet here.
        data: { myVal : myVal  }
      }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
}
```

Read more: http://javabelazy.blogspot.com/2012/08/jquery-ajax-call-to-servlet-example.html#ixzz2MxBBouHP